# Make a new function (method) that takes two doubles as input and return the biggest one

Tags: java

I don't understand how to make two doubles as input and return the biggest number.

> Make a new function (method) that takes two doubles as input and return the biggest one.

My solution (trying an if-statement):

```
public class ex1DoubleFunction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double a = 10;
        double b = 20;
        System.out.println(doublefun(a, b));

    public static doublefun(a,b) {
        if (a>b) {
            return a;
        }

        else if (a<b) {
            return b;
        }
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the function supposed to do if the results are equal?

Comment: Your problem is the function declaration--you need the types.  public static double doubleFun(double a, double b) should make your code work as is.  Oh, also move it outside of the "main" function.  Your indentation is good so the fact that you have 2 close braces in a row at the same level should be an indication that there is something wrong.

Comment: As tague suggested, you might also want to get rid of the last comparison and just have it return b for safety (If a's not bigger, b will be, right?)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple task, the solution below should do.

```
public static double findMax(double numOne, double numTwo){ // parameters
  return Math.max(numOne,numTwo);  // built in class to find the max of two nums or more
}
```

Also, make sure you don't put this function inside the main method because it won't work. put this inside the same class as the main method for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

This is also consider if you have equals value.

```
public static double whichGreater(double first, double second) {
   if(first >= second){
     return first;
   } else {
     return second;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
public static double doublefun(double a, double b) {
   if ( a > b) {
     return a;
   } else {
     return b;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ternary operator.

```
return (a>b)?a:b;
```